# Highlight cells with duplicate values, but each duplicate value a unique color. Excel Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, duplicates, formatting, conditional-statements, highlight

Basically I'd like to highlight all duplicate cells with duplicate values. I've used conditional formatting to do this. The twist is, I would like each different, duplicate value to be highlighted a unique color.

For example,
If apple was found in three different cells, highlight them all red.
If orange was found in two different cells, high them all blue
etc. etc. and this will go on for hundreds of different, duplicate values... So I need it to generate slightly unique colors as well.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**EDIT:** I found a solution at this website: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3772-excel-highlight-duplicate-values-in-different-colors.html although it costs money to install, this module, so if anyone has a different solution it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can close this question by posting and accepting your own answer. Not suggesting to delete it.  Better post the solution in answer here instead of just a link.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution that uses KUTOOlS which can be found at the following website: 
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3772-excel-highlight-duplicate-values-in-different-colors.html

Insert a module in VBA and enter the following code:

```
Sub ColorCompanyDuplicates()
'Updateby Extendoffice 20160704
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xTxt As String
Dim xCell As Range
Dim xChar As String
Dim xCellPre As Range
Dim xCIndex As Long
Dim xCol As Collection
Dim I As Long
On Error Resume Next
If ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Count > 1 Then
  xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal
Else
  xTxt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AddressLocal
End If
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("please select the data range:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
xCIndex = 2
Set xCol = New Collection
For Each xCell In xRg
  On Error Resume Next
  xCol.Add xCell, xCell.Text
  If Err.Number = 457 Then
    xCIndex = xCIndex + 1
    Set xCellPre = xCol(xCell.Text)
    If xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex = xCIndex
    xCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex
  ElseIf Err.Number = 9 Then
    MsgBox "Too many duplicate companies!", vbCritical, "Kutools for Excel"
    Exit Sub
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0
Next
  End Sub
```

Then press F5 to run the module.

(**NOTE**: This only works with KUTOOLS installed)

Comment: Looks like Kutools Marketing for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ColorCompanyDuplicates()
'Updateby Extendoffice
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xChar As String
    Dim xCellPre As Range
    Dim xCIndex As Long
    Dim xCol As Collection
    Dim I As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Count > 1 Then
      xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal
    Else
      xTxt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AddressLocal
    End If
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("please select the data range:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    xCIndex = 2
    Set xCol = New Collection
    For Each xCell In xRg
      On Error Resume Next
      xCol.Add xCell, xCell.Text
      If Err.Number = 457 Then
        xCIndex = xCIndex + 1
        Set xCellPre = xCol(xCell.Text)
        If xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex = xCIndex
        xCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex
      ElseIf Err.Number = 9 Then
        MsgBox "Too many duplicate companies!", vbCritical, "Kutools for Excel"
        Exit Sub
      End If
      On Error GoTo 0
    Next
End Sub
```

Found this VBA for Excel, it worked for me to organize and highlight multiple duplicates in different colors. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).